# Is OnItemClickListener only supposed to work for one list item at the time?

Tags: android

I set up an `onItemClickListener()` for my `ListView`. To me the name suggests *the event should be fired after a click on any individual item off the list view*. In my application, I have multiple selection for my items, and the `onitemclicklistener()` only responds to the first item that is clicked. Is this how it's supposed to work? If so, are there any alternatives to have a `onClickListener()` for each individual list item? Thanks

Some code:

```
listView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener(){

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapter, View view, int position,
                    long id) {
                ListView listView = getListView();
                listView.setItemChecked(position, true);
                Log.v("onItemClick","set checked");
```

the message in `log` is:

`logged only on any item of the list that is being clicked first. Clicking on another item does not invoke the listener, as the message is not being logged.`

Comment: onItemClickListener is invoked when an item in the ListView has been clicked. You have to ckeck your implementation

Comment: When I started out I kept forgetting the I implementation too. One day, I asked for onTouchListeners (very similar). Here you go http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17864143/single-method-to-implement-ontouchlistener-for-multiple-buttons

Answer (score 0):

Did you try?

```
getListView().setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE);
```

Comment: Ok this does indeed allow to invoke listener for multiple list items, however contextual action bar is now not opening. When I use CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE_MODAL, it is the opposite: CAB opens up, but only one list item responds to the listener. Before anyone asks, I need the listener to access the View of each item, which I cannot do in onItemCheckedStateChanged() method. Thanks for the answer anyway (sorry I can't upvote it)

Comment: Hm, you know you get the view with the event... public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapter, VIEW view, int position,
                    long id)??

Comment: yeah can do it for one list item, as the rest do not invoke onItemClick() method