# Do I need to declare buttons with onCreate() aswell or "setid" is enough?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, button, event-handling

I found [this answer from @anthonycr](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17864346/13095326) and lacked the reputation required to comment. However, I could use some clarification.

Do I need additional declaring button in `onCreate` method or for example `m1.setid` is enough? If I have too many buttons(50) how can I declare it without  writing 50 lines of `Button btn = (Button) findviewbyId(R.id.x)`?

Find my code below regarding `OnTouchListener`. However, I need to declare my buttons  with `findviewbyId`? If so , how can I declare  50 buttons without writing 50 lines of `findviewbyId`

````
void intialization(){
     Button m1, m2, m3, m4;
     ... //do initialization stuff
     m1.setId(1);
     m2.setId(2);
     m3.setId(3);
     m4.setId(4);
     MyTouchListener touchListener = new MyTouchListener();
     m1.setOnTouchListener(touchListener);
     m2.setOnTouchListener(touchListener);
     m3.setOnTouchListener(touchListener);
     m4.setOnTouchListener(touchListener);
 }

    
public class MyTouchListener implements OnTouchListener {
    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        switch(v.getId()){
            case 1:
                //do stuff for button 1
                break;
            case 2:
                //do stuff for button 2
                break;
            case 3:
                //do stuff for button 3
                break;
            case 4:
                //do stuff for button 4
                break;
        }
        return true;
    }

}```
````

Comment: Added link to original answer, improved grammar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Store them in an `array`:

```
Button[] buttons = new Button[50];
for (int i=0;i<50;i++)
{
   //I imagine this is a constructor that sets the given number into the button id.
   buttons[i]=new Button(i); 
   //but you can also set it after creating it (just choose one option)
   buttons[i].setId(i);
}
```

After it, calling a button should like to:

```
/*I'm guessing "1" will be the input to choose the first one.
 As arrays start at 0, I decrement the id by 1.*/

Button choosenOne = buttons[v.getId()-1];

//and now do whatever with the selected button
choosenOne.doStuff();
```

Comment: Take a look at more flexible specifications such as ArrayList, HashMaps, etc. Arrays are basic, sometimes you'll need something more. You're welcome

Comment: Yes for sur, i know and i can use arrays, for loops, classes , inheritance , implements, polymorphism. But as you know aran when it is time to connect everything together, need to years of experience.

Comment: You are on the right way, don't bother about how much you'll need. Little by little Rome was done